# Why does the text have dotted underline in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, microsoft-word-365

Suddenly a dotted line appeared under some text I was typing in Word for Microsoft 365 version 2302. It doesn't go away when I add or remove underline. What is this dotted line?

[image]

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates that the text has a ["Hidden" effect](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-hidden-text-word/) applied to it which might happen accidentally if the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+H is pressed. This can be removed through selecting the text and opening the "Font" menu (shortcut Ctrl+D), and unchecking the "Hidden" box under "Effects", or quicker by selecting the text and pressing the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+H again.

Note that the dotted lines (and the hidden text) are only visible when the "show paragraph marks" option is active.